# When will elementaryOS based on 18.04 LTS be released?

Tags: release-juno

I am just wondering when the new elementaryOS based on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS will be released, as LTS will be soon available and I am looking to upgrade. I want to make sure I choose correctly as I will be using it for the next 2 years.

Comment: When it's ready. But based off the posts from the developers it looks to be soon-sh after the release of Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Is there any ETA for Elementary OS based on 18.04 LTS ?

Comment: [It was released in October 2018](https://itsfoss.com/elementary-os-juno-features/)

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://itsfoss.com/elementary-os-juno-features/) states that it won’t be released before April but it should not be going as far as September.

Comment: That article that instructs you how to try "the beta" is not a good thing to suggest people do.

First of all, it's not "the beta", as no beta has been released by elementary yet. It won't be a stable configuration or representative of the final install of Juno.

I would suggest editing your answer to warn people of this.

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect the changes. Thanks